# Can I cast a glow in the dark flower in resin?

Tags: preservation, flowers, mold-making

This is my first time experimenting with resin. What [I want to create is a glow in the dark version of preserved flower](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/how-can-i-make-my-flowers-glow-in-the-dark?noredirect=1&lq=1) in resin.

Based on [this thread](http://chemistry.about.com/od/glowingprojects/a/Glowing-Flower.htm), it's possible to create glow in the dark flowers. So, in order to keep it lasting a long time I am planned to make an ornament like this:

[image: Flower ornament]

However I want to use a glow in the dark flower instead.

Sadly, given my condition, getting my hands on the materials such as resin and the glow in the dark paint is not easy, so waste (or do "let's just try it first") them is hardly an option. Therefore, I want to make sure that every step that I'll take basically works as I can't afford to experiment.

Because this is an amateur resin casting project I want to do this with as basic items as I can. I've been exploring the internet, but it seems the most common item do cast a resin is a silicone mold. Can it be done with either of these containers?
[image: Small Plastic Tub][image: Tupperware container]

Because so far the only limitation that I have found (based on my limited research) is "don't use a wax container".

Comment: Can you clarify what part of the process you want help with? Based on what you have found so far, it's possible to preserve a flower in resin and possible to make a fluorescing flower -- asking if anybody's done this before doesn't really seem on topic, but asking for tips on a particular part of the process would be.

Comment: Hi @Erica . I'm really sorry. I'm new to this group and now I realize that my question is kinda out of topics. I'll update my question. Sorry :)

Comment: This is a lot better, I am glad you've got specifc detailed questions now. But... can you ask it as two separate questions (use this for the resin casting, open a new one for the flower dying/coloring)? We really love having questions, and the two parts of the process are different enough that you'll likely find different "specialists" able to address the two parts :) Thanks!

Comment: @Erica Thanks for the warm response! Roger that

Comment: Since the question got split I removed some of the text that didnt need to be there and tried to clean it up a bit. Forgive me if I changed too much. Also linked to the other question.

Comment: The thing about a silicone mould is that you can pull the cast item out through a small hole as it stretches.  You can *probably* make your own mould by casting bathroom sealant around an item of the right shape, using a mould release fluid (oil).  Perhaps you could practise the casting process with cheap epoxy, which won't set clear but may help you troubleshoot any handling issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few comments about the problem as a whole, before I address your specific question...

You are attempting to encapsulate something in a clear resin shell.  That shell lacks any distinct shape, being comprised of flat planes and soft organic curves.  It does not contain any sharply detailed features or surface textures.  In short, the shell probably does not contain any aspects which need to be captured by an advanced casting medium like silicone.

Consider [Casting a mold using a mixture of Gelatin/Glycerin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIj_I6mW5QQ).  This avoids much of the cost of casting silicone.  Silicone is better in my experience for capturing details, but for your project, gelatin will probably work fine.

On a different subject, clear resins are notorious for capturing air bubbles which may detract from the look that you are pursuing.  There are techniques for reducing those bubbles but the only way to completely eliminate them is to use a vacuum chamber.  Here are some [instructions on creating a cheap vacuum chamber](http://www.instructables.com/id/make-a-manual-vacuum-pump-for-under-$20-by-convert/).

Now for your actual question...

The containers which you show are suitable for holding your mold.  I prefer the red Wall's container because it seems to widen near the top.  That will make removing the mold from the container easier and leave the container intact between castings.  That way, once you have cut your original out of the mold, you can return the empty mold to the container to support its original shape during the application and curing of the resin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate that. It turns out that the Wall's container melt (maybe due to the corrosive property of resin) and the plastic container works well (but lack of "interesting shape")

Comment: Melting!  Didn't think that would be a problem.  Resin does give off some heat while it cures, but the outer shell is usually insulated by the mold (either silicon or gelatin).  Are you filling the whole container with resin such that your finished item is the shape of the container?

Comment: No, I just pour 1/8 resin to the container. The shape is the same as the container, and the melted part does not interfere with resin though.

Comment: I'm happy that your technique is working for you.  If you decide to look into getting more control of your resin's final shape, look into mold making.  With a little creativity and some silicon (or geletin) you can create resin castings of any shape imaginable.

Comment: There is a consistent misspelling in this answer. “Silicon” is a chemical element (a metal) used to make integrated circuits. It is not suitable for mold making unless you have equipment for high-temperature metal forging. “Silicone” on the other hand is a rubbery material often used to make molds, often available as two-part mixtures specifically for mold making, or one-part mixtures often sold as aquarium sealant, bathroom caulk, and other uses.

Comment: Thanks @SomeGuy.  I have fixed my answer